# play and stop flash with jquery

Tags: jquery, flash

```
<div id="flashContent">
            <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="433" height="206" id="Untitled-2" align="middle">
                <param name="movie" value="http://marinegyulumyan.com/_resource/templates/default/flash/01.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#0d0a0a" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="Untitled-2.swf" width="433" height="206">
                    <param name="movie" value="http://marinegyulumyan.com/_resource/templates/default/flash/01.swf" />
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#0d0a0a" />
                    <param name="play" value="true" />
                    <param name="loop" value="true" />
                    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                    <param name="menu" value="true" />
                    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                    <param name="salign" value="" />
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                    </a>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
            <a href="" class="play">play</a>
            <a href="" class="pause">pause</a>
        </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
          $(".play").live("click", function() {
              if($('param[name=play]').attr('value') == false){
                  $('param[name=play]').attr('value','true');
              }else { $('param[name=play]').attr('value','true');}
              return false;
          });
          $(".pause").live("click", function() {
              if($('param[name=play]').attr('value') == true){
                  $('param[name=play]').attr('value','false');
              }else  { $('param[name=play]').attr('value','false');}
              return false;
          });
        </script>
```

How to stop the motion of a Flash Player by clicking a link??? See my code where I used jQuery and please tell me what did I do wrong??

Answer (score 1):

i don't think you can update "params" after initializing the `object`. try using ActionScript's `ExternalInterface`. with it you can define function that can be called via JS.

here's an example:
http://blog.deconcept.com/code/externalinterface.html

in your case you just have to call a function inside your flash movie, that just does `play();` or `stop();`

Comment: so you don't have access to the SWF? or could you add some code snippets into the SWF?

Comment: if so, could you post the right code here? i'm interested in how to do this.

Comment: `<style type="text/css">
  .packet {
   background: url(1.jpg) no-repeat;
   width: 429px;
   height: 192px;
  }

  .packet img {
   margin: 4px 0 0 236px;
   position: relative;
  }

  .packet img:hover {
   -moz-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
   -webkit-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
  }

  @-moz-keyframes spin {
   0% { -moz-transform:rotate(0deg); }
   100% { -moz-transform:rotate(360deg); }
  }
 </style>


<div class="packet">
 <img src="2.png" alt=""/>
</div>`